# Convert multiple time format object as datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe with a list of time value as object and needed to convert them to `datetime`, the issue is, they are not on the same format so when I try:

```
df['Total call time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Total call time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

it gives me an error

```
ValueError: time data '3:22' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)
```

or if use this code

```
df['Total call time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Total call time'], format='%H:%M')
```

I get this error

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: :58
```

These are the values on my data

```
Total call time
2:04:07
3:22:41
2:30:41
2:19:06
1:45:55
1:30:08
1:32:15
1:43:28
**45:48**
1:41:40
5:08:37
**3:22**
4:29:05
2:47:25
2:39:29
2:29:32
2:09:52
3:31:57
2:27:58
2:34:28
3:14:10
2:12:10
2:46:58
```

Comment: If those are elapsed times, you need to use `pd.to_timedelta`, not `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: to parse to a duration (timedelta), you'll need to ensure consistent HH:MM:SS format first, e.g. [as I show here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72541391/10197418) (note: use `zfill(8)` for your data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
times = """\
2:04:07
3:22:41
2:30:41
2:19:06
1:45:55
1:30:08
1:32:15
1:43:28
45:48
1:41:40
5:08:37
3:22
4:29:05
2:47:25
2:39:29
2:29:32
2:09:52
3:31:57
2:27:58
2:34:28
3:14:10
2:12:10
2:46:58""".split()

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(times, columns=['elapsed'])
def pad(s):
    if len(s) == 4:
        return '00:0'+s
    elif len(s) == 5:
        return '00:'+s
    return s
print(pd.to_timedelta(df['elapsed'].apply(pad)))
```

Output:

```
0    0 days 02:04:07
1    0 days 03:22:41
2    0 days 02:30:41
3    0 days 02:19:06
4    0 days 01:45:55
5    0 days 01:30:08
6    0 days 01:32:15
7    0 days 01:43:28
8    0 days 00:45:48
9    0 days 01:41:40
10   0 days 05:08:37
11   0 days 00:03:22
12   0 days 04:29:05
13   0 days 02:47:25
14   0 days 02:39:29
15   0 days 02:29:32
16   0 days 02:09:52
17   0 days 03:31:57
18   0 days 02:27:58
19   0 days 02:34:28
20   0 days 03:14:10
21   0 days 02:12:10
22   0 days 02:46:58
Name: elapsed, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to grovina's answer ... instead of using apply you can directly use the `dt` accessor.

Here's a sample:

```
>>> data = [['2017-12-01'], ['2017-12- 
30'],['2018-01-01']]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, 
columns=['date'])
>>> df
         date
0  2017-12-01
1  2017-12-30
2  2018-01-01
>>> df.date
0    2017-12-01
1    2017-12-30
2    2018-01-01
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Note how df.date is an object? Let's turn it into a date like you want

```
>>> df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
>>> df.date
0   2017-12-01
1   2017-12-30
2   2018-01-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

The format you want is for string formatting. I don't think you'll be able to convert the actual datetime64 to look like that format. For now, let's make a newly formatted string version of your date in a separate column

```
>>> df['new_formatted_date'] = 
df.date.dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
>>> df.new_formatted_date
0    01/12/17 00:00
1    30/12/17 00:00
2    01/01/18 00:00
Name: new_formatted_date, dtype: object
```

Finally, since the df.date column is now of date datetime64... you can use the dt accessor right on it. No need to use apply

```
>>> df['month'] = df.date.dt.month
>>> df['day'] = df.date.dt.day
>>> df['year'] = df.date.dt.year
>>> df['hour'] = df.date.dt.hour
>>> df['minute'] = df.date.dt.minute
>>> df
        date new_formatted_date  month  day  
year  hour  minute
0 2017-12-01     01/12/17 00:00     12    
1  2017     0       0
1 2017-12-30     30/12/17 00:00     12   
30  2017     0       0
2 2018-01-01     01/01/18 00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is test if double `:` and if not added `:00` with converting to timedeltas by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), also is test if number before first `:` is less like `23` - then is parsing like `HH:MM`, if is greater is parising like `MM:SS`:

```
m1 = df['Total call time'].str.count(':').ne(2)
m2 = df['Total call time'].str.extract('^(\d+):', expand=False).astype(float).gt(23)
s  = np.select([m1 & m2, m1 & ~m2], 
               ['00:' + df['Total call time'], df['Total call time']+ ':00'],
                df['Total call time'] )
df['Total call time'] = pd.to_timedelta(s)
print (df)
   Total call time
0  0 days 02:04:07
1  0 days 03:22:41
2  0 days 02:30:41
3  0 days 02:19:06
4  0 days 01:45:55
5  0 days 01:30:08
6  0 days 01:32:15
7  0 days 01:43:28
8  0 days 00:45:48
9  0 days 01:41:40
10 0 days 05:08:37
11 0 days 03:22:00
12 0 days 04:29:05
13 0 days 02:47:25
14 0 days 02:39:29
15 0 days 02:29:32
16 0 days 02:09:52
17 0 days 03:31:57
18 0 days 02:27:58
19 0 days 02:34:28
20 0 days 03:14:10
21 0 days 02:12:10
22 0 days 02:46:58
```